# simple deque programme exhibit weird behaviour

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, deque

I am using a deque to store integers from 1 to 10 and output to console 1 to 10 but for some unknown reason it outputs 11 for every loop . I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;




int main()
{
    deque <int> deq;

    int i;

    for ( i= 1 ;i <=10 ;i++)
    {
       deq.push_front(i);
    }

    deque <int>::iterator d2;

    d2 = deq.begin();

    while (d2 != deq.end() )
    {
        cout<<i
            <<endl;

            d2++;
    }


}
```

**Thanks for the help , i understand the problem already**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print out the value contained by the iterator, not `i`:

```
while (d2 != deq.end() )
{
    // wrong!
    //cout<<i
    //    <<endl;

    cout << *d2 << endl;

        d2++;
}
```

As a side note, this illustrates why you should always limit the scope of variables to the smallest possible scope.  Had your original loop been declared as:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
```

Then attempting to print out `i` (incorrectly) later would have been a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `i`, which was assigned to `i=11` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this

```
cout << i << endl;
```

with something that actually remove things from the dequeue:

```
cout << deq.pop_front() << endl;
```

To avoid simple errors like this in the future, restrict the scope of loop index variables by declaring them inside the loop header:

```
for (int i= 1 ;i <=10 ;i++)
{
   deq.push_front(i);
}
```

This way you would get a compile error trying to reference `i` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    deque <int> deq;

    int i;

    for ( i= 1 ;i <=10 ;i++)
    {
       deq.push_front(i);
    }
```

===> `i` is 11 here `(i <= 10)` is false at 11

```
    deque <int>::iterator d2;

    d2 = deq.begin();
```

===> here you really want to use `d2`

```
    while (d2 != deq.end() )
    {
        cout<<i
```

===> here you print `i` instead of `d2`

```
             <<endl;


            d2++;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print i inside the while loop it produce always 11 because above your code. You already use int i in the for loop, with the last value is 10. Debug your code with ddebugging tools ini your editor again, you will know what you'r doing wrong.

```
while (d2 != deq.end() )
{
cout<<i<<endl;
d2++;
}
```

The above while always produce 11 every iteration.